# Group of consecutive minimum values within data - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have daily river flow data for 1975-2009 and I am asked to find the 7 consecutive days within each year that have the smallest flows.

Any advice how to start this? I've only been using MATLAB for a couple weeks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could convolve the data with `ones(1,7)` and look for the minimum, which will yield the starting day of your dry period:

```
[~,startingDay] = min(conv(flow,ones(1,7),'valid'))
```

(This is basically a moving average filter without the normalization).
Loop through the years to get each year's result.

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding cumulative sum with [cumsum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html). The difference between cumulative sums 7 days apart will give you the total for those 7 days. Then pick the [minimum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) of those.

```
a = cumsum(flow);
b = a(8:end) - a(1:end-7);
[m,i] = min(b);
```

Here `m` holds the smallest total over 7 consecutive days, and `i` is a vector of indices telling you when they occurred.